# the image lose the quality when I save it

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a view with two uiimagesviewa inside of it, when i try to save those two images to the library, the image (containing the two images) loses the quality, what can I do to maintain the quality ? I am using this code

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_viewPhoto.bounds.size);
[_viewPhoto.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *MergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(MergedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

SOLVED

I solved this by changing this line

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_viewPhoto.bounds.size);
```

to

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_viewPhoto.bounds.size, NO, 0);
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008872/control-image-quality-with-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum

Comment: It did not help :( any other idea?